# Enable UTF-8 support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

How do I enable UTF-8 support in Ruby Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://woss.name/blog/2006/10/25/migrating-your-rails-application-to-unicode.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Ruby and Rails have been fully UTF8 ready for years.
See SLaks' answer for instructions.